# Why do links fade in this CSS Content Filter?

Tags: html, css, filter, content-management-system

I downloaded a copy of the [CSS-Only Content Filter](http://fofwebdesign.co.uk/template/_testing/filter/filter.htm) and add tried to add links to the filtered items. This is not working. Plain text is visible but links fade out.
When I tried increasing the opacity, this resulted in everything visible.
I really don't want to use Javascript or JQuery because I'll be using this on a site with its own presets for JS.
What did I miss?

**HTML**

```
<span class="filter-text">Filter:</span>
<input type="radio" id="filter-all-demo1" class="filter-input" name="filter" checked /><label for="filter-all-demo1" class="filter-label" onclick>All</label>
<input type="radio" id="blue-demo1" class="filter-input" name="filter" /><label for="blue-demo1" class="filter-label" onclick>Blue</label>
<input type="radio" id="red-demo1" class="filter-input" name="filter" /><label for="red-demo1" class="filter-label" onclick>Red</label>
<input type="radio" id="green-demo1" class="filter-input" name="filter" /><label for="green-demo1" class="filter-label" onclick>Green</label>

<div class="filter-wrap-demo1">
<div class="filter-item blue"><a href="#">Text with Link</a></div>
    <div class="filter-item red">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item green">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item red">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item blue">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item red">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item green">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item blue">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item green">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item red">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item green">Text without Link</div>
    <div class="filter-item blue">Text without Link</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font: 1em/1.75 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

#header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 4.0625em;
    background: #222
}

#header img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    left: 1em;
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    border: 0
}

#header>span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.175em;
    left: 5em;
    color: #fff
}

#header span+a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.65em;
    right: 0.5em;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none
}

#header a span {
    font-size: 1.5em
}

.page-content {
    padding: 0 1em 1em;
    max-width: 64em;
    margin: auto
}

.breadcrumbs {
    font-size: .75em;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #eee;
    margin: 0 -1.25em 1.5em;
    padding: 1em 1.25em
}

.breadcrumbs span {
    display: none
}

@media(min-width:30em) {
    .breadcrumbs {
        line-height: 3.75;
        padding: 0 1.25em
    }
}

@media(min-width:60em) {
    .breadcrumbs span {
        display: inline-block
    }
}

a,
a:active,
a:visited {
    color: #c30;
    opacity: 1
}

a:visited {
    color: #c90
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none
}

code {
    display: block;
    background: #ebebeb;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap
}

blockquote {
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0 5%
}

.filter-text,
.filter-label {
    font-size: 0.75em
}

.filter-label {
    margin: 0 5px;
    background: #acacac;
    padding: 20px 50px 50px 10px;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: white;
}

.filter-wrap-demo1,
.filter-wrap-demo2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.filter-item {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.27, 1.55);
}

#blue-demo1:checked~.filter-wrap-demo1 :not(.blue),
#red-demo1:checked~.filter-wrap-demo1 :not(.red),
#green-demo1:checked~.filter-wrap-demo1 :not(.green) {
    opacity: 0.1
}

#blue-demo2:checked~.filter-wrap-demo2 :not(.blue),
#red-demo2:checked~.filter-wrap-demo2 :not(.red),
#green-demo2:checked~.filter-wrap-demo2 :not(.green) {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

#blue-demo2:checked~.filter-wrap-demo2 :matches(.blue),
#red-demo2:checked~.filter-wrap-demo2 :not(.red),
#green-demo2:checked~.filter-wrap-demo2 :not(.green) {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
}
@media(min-width:30em) {
.filter-text,
.filter-label {
    font-size: 1em
}
}
input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't try to skirt around the code requirement. Post the relevant part of the code directly inside the question.

Comment: Does anyone know?